# ASP.NET Core MVC ChallengeResult, AuthenticationProperties argument is not received at the redirected action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-authentication, .net-security

I have a very basic authentication setup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie();
    }
}
```

Now when the MVC `ChallengeResult` is returned (with a `AuthenticationProperties` argument):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return View();    
        }
    }
}
```

The request is redirected to `/Account/Login` and to the following action method:

[image]

Issue: the original assignment of `IsPersistent = true` in the `Index()` action method is missing when the execution reach the `Login()` action method.

The App is built in: `.NET Core 3.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `properties` in action `login` is a new instance. It will be always null. Because you do not assign a value on a request. After returning to `Challenge`, the authentication will initiate a redirect. But the redirect will not carry this parameter.

You can set an event to save the value of the cookie authentication context in the session.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication("auth")
            .AddCookie("auth",config=>
            {
                config.Cookie.Name = "cookie.name";

                config.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Properties",System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(context.Properties));
                    context.Response.Redirect("/home/login");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

In action `login`.

```
public IActionResult login()
    {
        var get=HttpContext.Session.GetString("Properties");
        var deserializer = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthenticationProperties>(get);
        return View();
    }
```

Then, the properties will be passed into login.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Might I suggest using `context.RedirectUri` instead of `/home/login` (so that we will have the `returnUrl`). Also do you advice against using querystring parms to send chosen properties (instead of Session)? and let the Model Binding to map to a `AuthenticationProperties`

Comment: Yes, I advice. But if you pass many other attributes or sensitive information, it is not recommended.